# Tick and cross after input - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

everybody. I want to display tick next to the input field if the user has written some text (or is still writing) and cross if the input field is empty.
This is my try:

```
$('#myForm input').blur(function (){
    if($(this).val() == '')
    {
        $(this).after("<img src='./media/img/cross.png' style='margin-top: 15px;'/>");
    }
});

$('#myForm input').keypress(function (){
    if($(this).val() != '')
    {
        $(this).after("<img src='./media/img/tick.png' style='margin-top: 10px; width: 1.5em; height: 1.5em;'/>");
    }
});
```

Upper code adds image whenever the user types a letter. How can I avoid this? Is there more elegant way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

This is my HTML:

```
<form id="myForm" name="loginForm">
    <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Username" id="username"/>
    <input type="password" class="input" placeholder="Password" id="password"/>
    <input type="submit" class="btns" value="Login" name="submitLogin"/>
</form>
```

Comment: "Upper code adds image whenever the user types a letter." .. Well it is what [`.keypress()`](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) is supposed to do. What did you expect ?

Comment: **"Is there more elegant way to do this?"** There are several ways to do this. You will have to show your HTML markup to let the community help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add both image tags to the html, and give them a class with `display: hidden`. Use your events not to add DOM elements with `.after()`, but use them to set or unset the hidden class on your imgs respectively, kinda like this:

```js
$('#myForm input').blur(function (){
        if($(this).val() == '')
        {
            $(this).next('.tick').addClass('hidden');
            $(this).next('.tick').next('.cross').removeClass('hidden');
        }
    });

    $('#myForm input').keypress(function (){
        if($(this).val() != '')
        {
            $(this).next('.tick').next('.cross').addClass('hidden');
            $(this).next('.tick').removeClass('hidden');
        }
    });
```

```css
.hidden {display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" name="loginForm">
    <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Username" id="username"/><img class="hidden tick" src="#" alt="tick" /><img class="hidden cross" src="#" alt="cross" /><br/>
    <input type="password" class="input" placeholder="Password" id="password"/><img class="hidden tick" src="#" alt="tick" /><img class="hidden cross" src="#" alt="cross" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" class="btns" value="Login" name="submitLogin"/>
</form>
```

Comment: it is not supposed to work as is, you need to fit it to your html which I don't know.

Comment: I added to my html two images both next to input fields. I gave them classes `.tick` and `.cross` with display hidden. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I edited and added a working example based on your code.